# I don't want a match if a character follows another character, which is optional

Tags: regex, perl, string-matching

I want to match any variant of "error" (lets assume case-insensitive across the board), which may or may not be followed by a character, and may or may not have an "s".

For example, if it has the following, return the matching line:

```
text error: more text
text error more text
text errors more text
text errors( more text
text errors: more text
text errors:more text
```

But if there is an equal sign shortly following, I don't want it to return the line.  For example:

```
text errors= more text
```

Basically, it's always "errors" when there is an "=" sign following "error" or "errors".

I am failing to come up with more than this:

```
(?i)errors?[^\=]
```

Case-insensitive, the characters e, r, r, o, r, and maybe an s, and not followed by a "=" is the way I read that.

```
1 sample text, more text, errors=123456 more text more text
2 drops=0 link status good errors=0 adapter
3 Error: process failed to start
4 process [ERROR] failed
5 this line might have both ERROR and error=5555 and more text
6 there might be a line that has error=0x02343329 ERROR and more text
```

I want lines 3, 4, 5, and 6 to be returned, not 1 or 2.

Not having success.  Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: `errors?` makes whole string `errors` optional. This is probably why 3-6 are not returned. You would want `error(s?)` instead.

Comment: Also equal sign does need escaping, so you should have `=` instead of `\=`.

Comment: @dzieciou "errors? makes whole string errors optional. " <-- WRONG, it only makes the `s` optional

Comment: I'm confused. Should "foo error=abc" match or not?

Comment: if any form of "error" (upper or lower, with or without an "s") is followed by an equal sign, I don't want it.  However, if the word "error" is found elsewhere in the line, I want a match.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Zero-width lookahead is a good answer. Try:

```
 (?i)(?!errors?=)error
```

where "`(?!errors?=)`" means "peek ahead to check that it does not match "errors?=".

UPDATED:
This is to explain an issue with the original regexp `(?i)errors?[^\=]` in the question:
The complication is how and when "greediness" (man perlre) isn't as greedy as it might be, to quote:

> By default, a quantified subpattern is "greedy", that is, it will match
>   as many times as possible (given a particular starting location) while
>   still allowing the rest of the pattern to match.

Note the second part of the sentence. The original expression `(?i)errors?[^\=]` will match "errors=" (or "errors") because "s?" is allowed to match 0 times to allow "[^=]" to match "s".
This is why it matches the 6 numbered lines.

What's happening inside the regex engine when such a match (*,+,? and others) is rejected is called "backtracking", the matching backs up and tries a different path to see if a better match to the *whole* regexp is possible. Independent subexpression (?>), lookarounds (?=) (?!) and their negative forms, can prevent or limit backtracking, as can using alternation, it seems everyone has a different preference because I think most of them appear here somewhere. Though no-one so far seems to have given the minimal no-backtracking change to your original regexp using the "possessive" ?+ form:

```
errors?+[^\=]
```

Comment: This one seems to work without fail.  I am seeing much of what I wanted to see.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure this would allow a line with both error and error=, and return it.  I'm really interested in error as long as it's not followed by =, but if error and error= are in the same line, I still want it returned.

Comment: Line 5 match works as expected.
Easy way to test is: 
  perl -ne '/(?i)(?!errors?=)error/ && print "MATCH:".$_ ;'
then type away...

Comment: @mr.spuratic: Just wanted to understand. `(?!errors?=)` looks how many characters ahead? In the whole string?

Comment: This is just wrong. The problem is **not** greediness - the only quantifier is `?` which will match `s` if at all possible. That is what is wanted.

Comment: @Borodin: the original regexp (?i)errors?[^\=] fails according to the explanation of greediness, it matches "errors" because it "s?" is allowed to match zero times in order for the "s" to match "[^=]".

Comment: @dzieciou it looks ahead 6 or 7 characters, just think of it as a precondition to the next part of the pattern being allowed. It's possible to use a shorter version as shown by Lindrian, but the long form is clearer IMHO.

Comment: @mr.spuratic: `s?` being allowed to match zero times isn't greediness!

Comment: @Borodin yes of course you're right, I'm not explaining it clearly... I meant to explain that "errors=" will match /errors?[^=]/ because s? is allowed to match 0 times because of the way greediness works, specifically to allow the rest of the pattern to match, ie [^=] to match "s".

Answer (score 1):

So many answers, so close all of them. What you want is this: `/error(?!s=)/im`

You don't need to use the inline groups, use the /i flag instead.

I might have missunderstood your question, I'm not sure. But if you want to disallow `error=blah` too, simply use `/error(?!s?=)/im` instead.

Demo+explanation: http://regex101.com/r/oE1eQ9

Answer (score 1):

So you want to match "error" as long as it's not followed by "=" or "s=". It's quite simple:

```
/error(?!=|s=)/
```

You could even write it as

```
/error(?!s?=)/
```

If you really wanted to match "errors" if possible (in order to set `${^MATCH}` or something), the you could use

```
/error(?![s=])|errors(?!=)/
```

You're having a problem because /`[^=]`/ matches "`s`".

Answer (score 0):

Try to use lookahead assertions:

```
(?i)errors?(?!\=)
```

Comment: How would that change the result if it is all about find a line with a match, not a matching substring?

Comment: Split the text by \n, then match every line with the regexp.

Comment: I meant there is no difference between `(?i)errors?(?!\=)` and `(?i)errors?[^\=]` if you want to return a line with a match.

Comment: @dzieciou yes there is, `[^\=]` consumes a character whereas `(?!=)` (no need for the backslash) doesn't.

Comment: It find matches in line 1 and 2, http://regex101.com/r/oM1wC4, which is not what OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

How about a logical OR?

```
(?i)error[^s=]|errors[^=]
```

Comment: The first part of the expression would match a line with `error=`, which is not what OP wanted.

Comment: @dzieciou I think you may have misunderstood what he wrote.  For example, look at test cases #5 and #6, which contain the substring 'error='.  Note that OP said that #5 and #6 are lines he wants returned.  Perhaps you're thinking of 'errors=' (i.e. plural)?

Comment: The question seems confusing, that's why we interpreted it differently. I understood 5th is returned because it contains the string `ERROR`. Also OP wrote "Case-insensitive, the characters e, r, r, o, r, and maybe an s, and not followed by a "=" is the way I read that."

Comment: Correct.  I think you understood.  I don't want error=, unless error is elsewhere, not followed by a =

Comment: @harperville Ok - now I'm confused.  In your description, you said "I want lines 3, 4, 5, and 6 to be returned".  Lines 5 and 6 both contain the substring 'error='.

Comment: Yes, but more importantly, it contains error by itself.  Its case (upper or lower) is not important but I want a string that has error, even if it has error= but I don't want the string if there is error= and no error by itself.  Also, I want strings that may just have error and no error=

Comment: When I use yours I get:

3 Error: process failed to start
4 process [ERROR] failed
5 this line might have both ERROR and error=5555 and more text
6 there might be a line that has error=0x02343329 ERROR and more text

Looks good to me!

Comment: Doesn't match if "error" or "errors" appears at the end of the line. For example, it won't match "foo error".

Comment: @ikegami Not true.  Doesn't match end-of-file, but will match end-of-line.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
(?i)\berror(?!s?=)
```

Word anchor, followed by `error`, as long as it is not followed by an optional `s` then an equal sign.

`(?!...)` is a negative lookahead, and is also an anchor (like `^` and `$`) in the sense that it does not consume text (it is a zero-width assertion).

Answer (score 0):

Oh dear. A lot of people think they know regular expressions!

In your own regex `(?i)errors?[^\=]` (where, as someone said, the `=` doesn't need escaping, but it does no harm) `[^\=]` doesn't quite mean "not followed by an equals sign", it means "followed by a character that's not an equals sign". The two are the same unless `error` is at the end of a string, so `'error' =~ (?i)errors?[^\=]` returns false.

"Not followed by an equals sign" requires the negative look-ahead, so at first sight it looks like you want `(?i)errors?(?!=)`, but if the regex engine finds `errors=` it will backtrack and try matching without the optional `s` to see if it can get the whole pattern to match that way, and will then succeed because `errors` is `error` not followed by an equals sign.

To fix this you need the no-backtrack construction `(?>...)` which will not allow backtracking once a match has been found. The regex `(?i)(?>errors?)(?!=)` does what you need.

Finally, to allow for the rejection of an equals sign "shortly after" `error` or `errors` you need some optional white space before it, giving `(?i)(?>errors?)(?!\s*=)`.

This program demonstrates

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  printf "%-70s %s\n", $_, /(?i)(?>errors?)(?!\s*=)/ ? 'YES' : 'NO';
}

__DATA__
text error: more text
text error more text
text errors more text
text errors( more text
text errors: more text
text errors:more text
text errors= more tex
text errors = more tex
text error= more tex
text error = more tex
1 sample text, more text, errors=123456 more text more text
2 drops=0 link status good errors=0 adapter
3 Error: process failed to start
4 process [ERROR] failed
5 this line might have both ERROR and error=5555 and more text
6 there might be a line that has error=0x02343329 ERROR and more text
```

**output**

```
text error: more text                                                  YES
text error more text                                                   YES
text errors more text                                                  YES
text errors( more text                                                 YES
text errors: more text                                                 YES
text errors:more text                                                  YES
text errors= more tex                                                  NO
text errors = more tex                                                 NO
text error= more tex                                                   NO
text error = more tex                                                  NO
1 sample text, more text, errors=123456 more text more text            NO
2 drops=0 link status good errors=0 adapter                            NO
3 Error: process failed to start                                       YES
4 process [ERROR] failed                                               YES
5 this line might have both ERROR and error=5555 and more text         YES
6 there might be a line that has error=0x02343329 ERROR and more text  YES
```